# social comments web part comment datetime

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, social

I am using sharepoint 2013 social comment web part in my custom aspx page as follows

```
 <SPSWC:SocialCommentWebPart runat="server"></SPSWC:SocialCommentWebPart>
```

Although this works fine, the commments section of this control shows , date of the comment posted in "yyyy dd mm hh mm" format.

I want to change this format to simly dd/mm/yyyy

Is it possible and how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(yourObject.ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string s = dt.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```